# Dynamic LayerGroups Leaflet

Tags: javascript, function, leaflet

I'm trying to simplify the code a bit and instead of using long "if/else" statement I testing to use a function with switch to be able to dynamically add named layerGroup to the Layer control in Leaflet. Styling works fine but trying to "addTo" using the same method does not work.... is this wrong way doing it or what is missing for it to work? It gives me error "TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function" and points error to the "addTo" line...

```
var point_A = new L.layerGroup();
var point_B = new L.layerGroup();
var point_C = new L.layerGroup();
var point_D = new L.layerGroup();
var point_E = new L.layerGroup();
var point_F = new L.layerGroup();
var point_G = new L.layerGroup();
var point_H = new L.layerGroup();
var point_I = new L.layerGroup();
var point_J = new L.layerGroup();
var point_K = new L.layerGroup();
var point_L = new L.layerGroup();
var point_M = new L.layerGroup();
var point_N = new L.layerGroup();


$.getJSON("../geodata/point.geojson", function(json) {
    
    function newPoint(t){
        switch (t){
            case 20:    return point_A; // Edit: Remove as text for all...
            case 21:    return 'point_B';
            case 22:    return 'point_C';
            case 29:    return 'point_D';
            case 30:    return 'point_E';
            case 34:    return 'point_F';
            case 40:    return 'point_G';
            case 49:    return 'point_H';
            case 56:    return 'point_I';
            case 58:    return 'point_J';
            case 66:    return 'point_K';
            case 69:    return 'point_L';
            case 99:    return 'point_M';
            case 100:   return 'point_N';
        }
    };      
    
    function newShape(t){
        switch (t){
            case 99:    return 'x';
            default:    return 'circle';
        }
    };
    
    function newRadius(d){
        switch (d){
            case 20:    return 10;
            case 21:    return 8;
            case 22:    return 6;
            case 29:    return 10;
            case 30:    return 6;
            case 34:    return 6;
            case 40:    return 10;
            case 49:    return 8;
            case 56:    return 4;
            case 58:    return 7;
            case 66:    return 6;
            case 69:    return 6;
            case 99:    return 12;
            case 100:   return 5;
        }
    };
    
    function newWeight(d){
        switch (d){
            case 56:    return 2;
            case 58:    return 3;
            case 99:    return 3;
            case 100:   return 2;
            default:    return 2;
        }
    };      
    
    function newColor(t){
        switch (t){
            case 22:    return '#ffffff';
            case 30:    return '#ffffff';
            case 56:    return '#0000ff';
            case 58:    return '#ffffff';
            case 99:    return '#ff0000';
            case 100:   return '#ffffff';
            default:    return '#ffffff';
        }
    };
    
    function newColorFill(t){
        switch (t){
            case 20:    return '#0000ff';
            case 22:    return '#0000ff';
            case 29:    return '#ff9900';
            case 30:    return '#cc0099';
            case 40:    return '#ff00ff';
            case 56:    return '#ffffff';
            case 58:    return '#252525';
            case 99:    return '#ff0000';
            case 100:   return '#ff0000';
            default:    return '#ffffff';
        }
    };          
            

geoLayer = L.geoJson(json, {
    
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        var point = newPoint(feature.properties.typeId); // Edit: remove this line
        var id = feature.properties.typeId;  
        var prod;
        
        prod = new L.shapeMarker(latlng, {
            radius: newRadius(id),
            fillColor: newColorFill(id),
            fillOpacity: 1,
            color: newColor(id),
            weight: newWeight(id),
            shape: newShape(id)
        }).addTo(point); //Edit: This work .addTo(newPoint(id));
        
      return prod;
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your switch case is returning *a string* of the name of the L.layerGroup you probably want to use:

```js
var point_A = new L.layerGroup();
var point_B = new L.layerGroup();
// ...


$.getJSON("../geodata/point.geojson", function(json) {
    
    function newPoint(t){
        switch (t){
            case 20:    return 'point_A';
            case 21:    return 'point_B';
            // ...
        }
    };
```

You need to return ana actual layerGroup to be able to call `.addTo` on it:

```js
    function newPoint(t){
        switch (t){
            case 20:    return point_A;
            case 21:    return point_B;
            // ...
        }
    };
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue, I also needed  to change "...addTo(newPoint(id));". Great I was on the right track and this saves me a lot of repeating if/else statements. Thanks